# rename files (preferably using python)

Tags: python, file, rename

I can not manage to solve a problem, hope you can help me.

I have several folders, containing files *.gz and I need to modify slightly the name as shown in the example below.

I was thinking about creating a dictionary with the `{filenames:[ list spliting by "_"]}` and then join again but changing the order of `001_R1` for `R1_001` to finally "`os.rename`", but there must be a better way.

Thanks for your help.

**Old name:**

```
Folder1/

F02_TAGCTT_L005_R1_001.fastq.gz

F02_TAGCTT_L005_R1_002.fastq.gz

Folder2/

J02_TAGCTT_L005_R1_001.fastq.gz

J02_TAGCTT_L005_R1_002.fastq.gz
```

**New name:**

```
Folder 1/

F02_TAGCTT_L005_001_R1.fastq.gz

F02_TAGCTT_L005_002_R1.fastq.gz

Folder2/

J02_TAGCTT_L005_001_R1.fastq.gz

J02_TAGCTT_L005_002_R1.fastq.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the GNU userspace, I'd use the rename command:

```
rename _R1_ _ *.gz

rename .fastq.gz _R1.fastq.gz *.gz
```

Otherwise, in Python, list the directories, filter on extension (or whatever), map the rename function and call `os.rename` on each pair of original and new names.

Comment: Hi Javier, thanks for your reply. The problem is that with rename I get this: F02_TAGCTT_L005_R1_001_R1.fastq.gz, but I need F02_TAGCTT_L005_001_R1.fastq.gz. Since the term "001" change across the files, I can't use rename. I will try in python following your advice. If get a proper script I will post it here

Comment: The first rename should remove the _R1_ and the second add the _R1 at the end. If you get two R1's, then the first rename is not working. Play with it until you get it right.

Comment: Right! I see it know. I got the same results using rename and the python script. I did not know about rename, nice to learn a new command.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution to my own problem. Since I have just started learning python, I am sure there are better ways to do it. Please, feel free to give me any advice. 
This is the script to rename the files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -tt

import os

def fq_filelist():fqlist=os.popen('ls *.gz').read().rstrip().split('\n')
       return fqlist

def split_filename():
  mydict = {}
  fqlist = fq_filelist()
  for i in fqlist:
    a = i.rstrip('.fastq.gz')
    for x in a:
      mydict[i] = [a.split('_')]
  return mydict

def myrename():
  mydict = split_filename()
  for i in mydict.keys():
      for x in mydict[i]:
        newname = x[0]+"_"+x[1]+"_"+x[2]+"_"+x[4]+"_"+x[3]+".fastq.gz"
        os.rename(i,newname)

myrename()
```